# How to MATCH a specific parent?

Tags: android, match

It seems to be simple. I want button2 to match button1. But when I insert "match_parent", button2 matches the main layout, and this results in the "full scale" to the sides. How can I fix it?

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Catálogo de Drogas"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mixador"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`button` is not the parent of `button2`, they're both at the same level in their common parent, the layout.

if I understand correctly (your question is unclear), you want `button2` width to match `button` width (which is wrap_content).

if so, and the parent layout is a `RelativeLayout`, you can align `button2` to `button`

```
<RelativeLayout (...)>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Catálogo de Drogas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        (...)
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Mixador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        (...)
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

if the buttons parent is a `LinearLayout`, the trick is to make it `wrap_content`

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Catálogo de Drogas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        (...)
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Mixador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        (...)
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"

WAS THAT I'M SEARCHING! THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: hehe no problem, please don't forget to accept the answer